Which $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ satisfies $\mathbb{C}[x,f] = k(x,f) \cap k[x,y]$?
Let $f=f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with $\deg_x(f) \geq 1, \deg_y(f) \geq 1$.

Question:
Which $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ satisfies $\mathbb{C}[x,f] = \mathbb{C}(x,f) \cap \mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Of course, always $\mathbb{C}[x,f] \subseteq  \mathbb{C}(x,f) \cap \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Remarks:
(1) There is a result concerning a Jacobian pair, namely, $(p,q) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]^2$ with $Jac(p,q) \in \mathbb{C}^*$, which says that $\mathbb{C}[p,q] = \mathbb{C}(p,q) \cap \mathbb{C}[x,y]$; it uses flatness of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ over $\mathbb{C}[p,q]$.
(2) $f=y$ satisfies $\mathbb{C}[x,y] = \mathbb{C}(x,y) \cap \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
(3) $f=xy$: $\mathbb{C}[x,xy] 
\subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y] = \mathbb{C}(x,xy) \cap \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Of course, $(x,xy)$ is not a Jacobian pair.
(4) $f=x+H(y)$, $H(T) \in \mathbb{C}[T]$, $\deg_T(H(T)) \geq 2$ :
$\mathbb{C}[x,x+H(y)] =\mathbb{C}[x,H(y)]$.
$\mathbb{C}(x,x+H(y))= \mathbb{C}(x,H(y))$.
It seems that $f=x+H(y)$ satisfies  $\mathbb{C}[x,f] = \mathbb{C}(x,f) \cap \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Notice that $(x,x+H(y))$ with $\deg_T(H(T)) \geq 2$, is not a Jacobian pair,
but it seems to satisfy the equality in the question.
A sufficient condition:
If $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is flat over $\mathbb{C}[x,f]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,f]^*=\mathbb{C}[x,y]^*=\mathbb{C}^*$, then $\mathbb{C}[x,f]=\mathbb{C}(x,f) \cap \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
In remark (4): $S:=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is flat over $R:=\mathbb{C}[x,x+H(y)]=\mathbb{C}[x,H(y)]$, by the argument in the first comment to this relevant question, and clearly $\mathbb{C}[x,x+H(y)]^*=k^*$, so the equality holds;
indeed, $S=\frac{R[T]}{\langle g \rangle}$, where $g=g(T)=H(T)-H(y)$ and the coefficients of $g(T)$ generate the unit ideal
(since the coefficients in H(T) are non-zero scalars).
Any comments are welcome; thank you.

I will give you an answer but leave all details to you.
Write $ f=a_0y^n+a_1y^{n-1}+\cdots +a_n$ where $a_i$ are polynomials in $x$. Notice that we may replace $ f$ by $g=f-a_n$ without loss of generality. Then your condition is equivalent to $\gcd(a_0,\ldots, a_{ n-1})=1$.

Thank you! The details appear in page 370 (between Theorem 6 and Theorem 9) in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266339075_Observations_about_the_Jacobian_conjecture
